# Postfix : Is it possible to set destination_concurrency_limit and rate_delay per sender?

Tags: postfix, centos6

Followed this tutorial to setup destination_rate_delay per recipient domain: http://steam.io/2013/04/01/postfix-rate-limiting/

The rate limiting is working, however, is it possible to only rate_limit an email such as newsletter@mydomain.com so that the admin@mydomain.com don't get rate limited?

main.cf

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport, regexp:/etc/postfix/transport.regexp

polite_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
polite_destination_rate_delay = 15s
polite_destination_recipient_limit = 5

turtle_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
turtle_destination_rate_delay = 30s
turtle_destination_recipient_limit = 2
```

I was looking of something along the lines of

```
*(other senders)@mydomain.com use default_limits
newsletters@mydomain.com use polite_turtle_limits
```

I don't believe policyd or postfwd would be used for this, am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the article you were following you created new transports and selected these transports per domain.

> The first step will be to edit the `master.cf` file and add SMTP
>   transports. Each transport will represent a policy for a group of
>   receiving domain:
>
> ```
> polite unix - - n - - smtp
> turtle unix - - n - - smtp
> ```
>
> Next, we need to map a domain to it’s transport name: Edit the
>   `/etc/postfix/transport` file and add the lines
>
> ```
> gmail.com polite:
> yahoo.com turtle:
> hotmail.com polite:
> ```

If you take a look at the documentation on [transport table format](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) you can figure out that it is perfectly possible to make these rules per recipient address in your `/etc/postfix/transport`, e.g.

```
newsletter@example.com polite:
example.com turtle:
```

Now, the `turtle` transport is used for every `example.com` mail that didn't match the per user setting.

Comment: What I am trying to ask is not per "recipient" but per "sender". So if newsletter@mydomain.com sends an email, apply the rules, if admin@mydomain sends the email, don't apply the rules.

Answer (score 0):

To use the from address to override the transport, you need to use [sender_dependent_default_transport_maps](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_default_transport_maps).

Make sure your `master.cf` file contains a `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` similar to this:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

Then edit `/etc/postfix/sender_transport` and add the following:

```
# use 'polite' transport for newsletter@mydomain.com
newsletter@mydomain.com      polite:
```

You need to create/update the lookup table every time after making changes to `sender_transport`:

```
cd /etc/postfix
postmap sender_transport
```

And probably reload postfix:

```
service postfix reload
```